# Nesting lists in dictionaries

Tags: python

I'd like to know the limitations regarding nesting in ***Dictionaries*** and ***Lists***.
The following code works fine.

```
dict = {
        'apples': {'typ1':'2.99','typ2':'2.49'},
        'oranges': '1.99',
        'berries':['blue', 'green', 'red']
       }
```

But if I try to create a dictionary inside the list under the key `'berries'` like this:

```
dict={
        'apples': {'typ1':'2.99','typ2':'2.49'}, 
        'oranges':'1.99', 
        'berries': [ blue = {'typ1':'3.99','typ2'='3.49'}, 'green', 'red']
     }
```

It doesn't work. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't call your dictionaries `dict`. This obscures the actual class `dict` in Python and makes it so that you can no longer refer to that class.

Now, `'berries': [ blue = {'typ1':'3.99','typ2'='3.49'}, 'green', 'red']` is the part that messes everything up because the syntax is invalid.

*Dictionaries*, defined using `{...}` have *keys* and *values*.

*Lists*, defined using `[...]` *cannot* have keys. Lists only have elements.

So you could define a list like `['blue', 'green', 'red']` and assign *that list* to the key `'berries'` like so:

```
mydict = { ...
         , 'berries': ['blue', 'green', 'red']
         }
```

You could even mix up the types of elements in the list, so this is also valid: `[{'color': 'blue', 'typ1': 3.99, 'typ2': 3.49}, 'green', 'red']`

Or you could define a *dictionary* like `{'blue': {...}, 'green': {...}, 'red': {...}}` and assign *that dict* to the key `'berries'` like so:

```
mydict = { ...
         , 'berries': {'blue': {...}, 'green': {...}, 'red': {...}}
         }
```

But you cannot assign a key-value pair in a list like you tried to do originally. Moreover, the `=` symbol is the wrong thing to use for a key-value pair anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`[blue={'typ1':'3.99','typ2'='3.49'},'green', ...]` this makes no sense. You're trying to assign something inside the array with the `=` operator. Its not a limitation, just wrong syntax. Also, changing the `=` to a `:` won't work aswell, because an array doesn't hold key-value pairs. So it seems like you're mixing up dictionaries and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see you create wrong format. You must follow the json format. 
Wrong format 
`'berries': [blue = {'typ1': '3.99', 'typ2' = '3.49'}, 'green', 'red']` 
so the above element will be modified as follows: 
`'berries': [{'blue': {'typ1': '3.99', 'typ2': '3.49'}}, 'green', 'red']}`

Also the type of the berries element is list so you must use the "append" function to add a new element. So the correct way is:
`dict['berries'].append({'blue': {'typ1': '3.99', 'typ2': '3.49'}})`

Summary code:

```
dict = {'apples': {'typ1': '2.99', 'typ2': '2.49'}, 'oranges': '1.99', 'berries': ['green', 'red']}
dict['berries'].append({'blue': {'typ1': '3.99', 'typ2': '3.49'}})
print(dict)
```

The expected result is:
`{'apples': {'typ1': '2.99', 'typ2': '2.49'}, 'oranges': '1.99', 'berries': ['green', 'red', {'blue': {'typ1': '3.99', 'typ2': '3.49'}}]}`